# Can I get information when locked in a Android App

Tags: android

I developed a android appli.
It's a widget.
and I wanna get information whether the display locked or not.
How can I do?

Comment: "I wanna get information whether the display locked or not" -- why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

boolean isDisplayLocked = keyguardManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();

if (isDisplayLocked) {

  //your code

}
```

Comment: Btw, looping this code in a widget will kill your battery life. The only intents you can listen to are screen on/off.

Comment: @Falmarri: actually, for screen lock, `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` is better than `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` -- the latter should fire just when the screen lights up, but the former should fire when the user dismisses the lock. Also, none of these `Intents` can be listened to by manifest-registered `BroadcastReceivers` and so are unsuitable for use by an app widget.